# Change picker font size on react-native-picker/picker lib

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-picker

I am trying to change the font size of the picker text itself (the button on which one clicks to get the modal opened) on the lib @react-native-picker/picker but cannot find a way to do it. There are a lot of issues raised on Stack Overflow about styling the items in the modal but I am fine with the standard white medium font, I just need to change the picker button.
I tried to style it the classic way but no chance so far, problem is that I am using expo and don't have the skills to do some native code.
Has anyone found a solution for that?
Many thanks